# Javascript promises: monitoring the state of an array

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say that I have an array of promises in Javascript, and I want them to resolve `n` promises at a time. What is a good way to do this?

Can I have a state array called `promisesInProgress` and have each promise monitor its length? On the outside, I will use Promise.all(). But within each promise, I want it to check the state array, promisesInProgress, and only fire when the length of that array is < n. Would that work?

What if I want to ensure that these promises don't resolve too fast, throttling them?

Is there a good pattern for this?

Comment: If you don't want promises to resolve (yet), you should delay their *creation*. Once created, they do their thing. So when you have (an array of) promises, you're already too late to do anything about delaying resolutions. Could you provide a concrete example in your question?

Comment: Once promises are created, their settlement is out of your hands; that is the business of whatever asynchronous process(es) the promises represent. You (or rather your code) is only in charge of what happens once the promises (individually and/or collectively) have settled.

Comment: So you have two basic choices, (i) control the rate at which the asynchronous process(es) are called or (ii) call the asynchronous process(es) as quickly a possible then control the rate at which the responses are processed. These may be design choices, or other factors may dictate that you do one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises "run" as soon as they come to existence, so when you have an array of those, you cannot expect to delay some of them.

What you could do however, is to work with an array of *functions* that -- when called -- would return a new promise. The `max` parameter would determine how many of those functions you would actually invoke immediately, while the remaining functions would only be called when "room" becomes available after one of the promises resolves.

Here is how you could do that:

```js
// Main function. 
// Parameters:
// - the maximum number of unresolved promises that may exist at a given time
// - an array of promise-creating functions 
function throttle(maxPending, asyncFuncs) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let numPending = 0;
        let nextFuncId = 0;
        const promisedValues = [];
        (function check() {
            if (nextFuncId >= asyncFuncs.length) { // All promises created
                if (numPending == 0) resolve(promisedValues); // All promises fulfilled
                return;
            }
            while (numPending < maxPending) { // Room for creating promise(s)
                numPending++;
                const thisFuncId = nextFuncId++;
                asyncFuncs[thisFuncId]().then(value => {
                    promisedValues[thisFuncId] = value;
                    numPending--;
                    check();
                }).catch(reject);
            }
        })();
    });
}

// Demo: 
// The usual delay function: returns a promise that resolves after given delay
const delay = (ms) => {
    console.log("Start delay of " + ms + "ms");
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
            .then(() => console.log("End delay of " + ms + "ms"));
};

// Curry for the above: pass the milliseconds and return a function 
//   that can create a promise for it
const delayF = (ms) => delay.bind(null, ms);

// Pass 5 promise-creating functions, but only allow 3 concurrently pending promises:
throttle(3, [delayF(1000), delayF(500), delayF(800), delayF(300), delayF(900)])
    .then(() => console.log("all done"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want them to resolve n promises at a time. What is a good way to do this?

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
const prom1 = Promise.resolve(1);
const prom2 = Promise.resolve(2);

Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(console.log);
```

> Can I have an array called promisesInProgress and have each promise monitor its length?

Yes but it's not a built-in, you can however code something similar as follow:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 2000)),
];
const resolved = promises.map(() => null);

promises.forEach((promise, index) => {
  promise.then(data => {
    resolved[index] = data;
    const nbResolved = resolved.filter(x => x!==null).length;
    console.log({resolved, nbResolved});
  })
});
```

> What if I want to ensure that these promises don't resolve too fast, throttling them?

You can delay their *creation*. Once a promise has been created, you can't slow it down.

> Is there a good pattern for this?

There isn't really anyy pattern for promises. They are as minimal as possible, letting you chose how to code them. I'd recommend to `async/await` to make your code flatter, though.

---

If you want to have many built-ins available for asynchronous code, Promises won't stand a chance agains [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/), a complex but very powerful library for handling async code. It has built-ins for throttling, piping, multicasting, and many more!

Comment: @BorisK is the code clear enough or should I add explanations? Do you require a code example for promises throttling, or RxJS usage?

Answer (score 0):

I think Promise.all() can work for you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Example:

```
Promise.all([
  getData('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db'),
  getData('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db')
]).then(
  json => console.log(json), // JSON obj
).catch(
  err => console.log(err.message) // // ERROR ERROR //
);
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer that only addresses part of the qestion

Comment: @Nino It's not link only. See, e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381637/1364007. It is an answer *with a link*, not a *link-only* answer. Not a good answer, but it is borderline an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I posted the comment before the edit, when it was a link-only answer

Answer (score 0):

First off, throttling is never the solution. You never want to stall the user experience. Without some code it's hard to determine what exactly you are attempting to do here, so an example would be nice.

There are a bunch of different ways to go about **tracking the progress** of a bunch of promises. But they mostly depend on what you want to track. Do you want to track when each individual promise is done? Simply refer to a function that increments a counter. To get the Progress Percentage simply do some basic math like below:

```
let promise_array = [...] // Your array of Promise objects
let counter = 0;
let total = promise_array.length

Promise.all(promise_array)

// inside each promise
counter++;

// to get progress
let progress = Math.round(counter/total*100,2)
```

If you want to get some other level of progress that occurs inside each promise then increment the counter whenever that progresses inside of each promise.

Comment: `First off, throttling is never the solution` yes it is - oftentimes async calls are costly (eg computationally intensive calculations, or calls to a not-free API) ;)

Comment: Perhaps you should read the following qualifying sentence, unless you believe throttling is okay in the context of the User Interface. Generally speaking it isn't, but since I imagine this comment was made in order to be technically correct rather than generally it won't matter.

Comment: I'm with @NinoFiliu, "First off, throttling is never the solution" is a poor opening sentence.

Comment: *"You never want to stall the user experience."*: the user experience may be harmed if you *don't* throttle, like when you query an API that has a maximum number of requests it allows to take in parallel. It would return errors and not the requested data.